# npx create-react-app get error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I'm using:

```
Windows 10
npm -v 5.8.0
npx -v 9.7.1
```

When running `npx`, I'm getting: `"The "path" argument must be of type string"`.

I am trying to create a React app. Get this error:

```
λ npx create-react-app myapp
npx: installed 1 in 4.576s

The "path" argument must be of type string
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\package.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 52
```

Comment: Can you show us what your `package.json` file looks like?

Comment: I had installed npm i create-react-app

Comment: Try newer version of node.js/npm, I had similar issue when switched to older node.js version.

Answer (score 3):

Before running

> npx create-react-app

you need to install create-react-app globally on your machine using

> npm install -g create-react-app

When this is successful, you can proceed to run the **npx** code as below

> npx create-react-app app-name

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Code-only answers can often be difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the error is important:

> C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\package.json:
>   Unexpected string in JSON at position 52

That means that your `package.json` file is not formatted correctly.

There are tools online such as [this](https://jsonlint.com/) which can help ensure that the formatting of your `package.json` is correct.

Comment: I had installed npm i create-react-app. I not do any changed in "package.json". Wthich trubles can accure ? Below package.json:

Comment: {
  "_from": "create-react-app",
  "_id": "create-react-app@1.5.2",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-vnYIzsfTaqai2l07P9qtxhsZgHbzirC2omxKmf16wqvpXao9CNCDmpk+BCZRElih7HTn/mpO3soe8DTZV4DsgQ==",
  "_location": "/create-react-app",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "tag",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "create-react-app",
    "name": "create-react-app",
    "escapedName": "create-react-app",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "latest"
  },

Comment: well, line 52   ],

Comment: },
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "createReactApp.js"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],

Comment: is it non working module "create-react-app" ? or I do some stupid mistake ?

Comment: thx for yr advise https://jsonlint.com/, I used one to check package.json. Results "Valid JSON"

Answer (score 0):

resolved.
Exist no one npx. U must call npx with full path:

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd create-react-app MyApp